# Invalid JSON produced during marshalling by MOXy

Tags: java, eclipselink, moxy

the following code produces invalid JSON during marshalling, but no exception is thrown.
If XML is used as marshalling format it works.

Looks like a bug or did i miss something?

I am using EclispseLink MOXy 2.5.1

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

public final class InvalidJsonApp {

    @XmlRootElement(name = "person")
    static class PersonEntity {

        private String firstname;

        @XmlElement(name = "phone")
        @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "person")
        private List<PhoneNumberEntity> phoneNumbers;

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumberEntity> phoneNumbers) {
            this.phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>(phoneNumbers);
        }

        public List<PhoneNumberEntity> getPhoneNumbers() {
            return phoneNumbers;
        }

        public void addPhoneNumber(PhoneNumberEntity phoneNumber) {
            if (phoneNumbers == null) {
                phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            this.phoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
        }

    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "phonenumber")
    static class PhoneNumberEntity {

        private String number;

        @XmlElement
        @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "phoneNumbers")
        private PersonEntity person;

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        void setPerson(PersonEntity person) {
            this.person = person;
        }

        PersonEntity getPerson() {
            return person;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        testPhoneNumber();
    }

    static void testPhoneNumber() throws JAXBException {
        System.out.println("phoneNumber:");
        PersonEntity personEntity = createPersonEntity();
        PhoneNumberEntity phoneNumberEntity = personEntity.getPhoneNumbers().get(0);
        String entityJson = marshal(phoneNumberEntity);
        System.out.println(entityJson);
        unmarshal(PhoneNumberEntity.class, entityJson);
    }

    static PersonEntity createPersonEntity() {
        PersonEntity person = new PersonEntity();
        person.setFirstname("yvonne");

        PhoneNumberEntity firstPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumberEntity();
        firstPhoneNumber.setNumber("12345");
        firstPhoneNumber.setPerson(person);

        PhoneNumberEntity secondPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumberEntity();
        secondPhoneNumber.setNumber("54321");
        secondPhoneNumber.setPerson(person);

        person.addPhoneNumber(firstPhoneNumber);
        person.addPhoneNumber(secondPhoneNumber);
        return person;
    }

    static String marshal(Object toMarshal) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {toMarshal.getClass()}, null);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
//        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(toMarshal, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    static <T> T unmarshal(Class<T> entityClass, String str) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {entityClass}, null);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
//        unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(str));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce the error that you are seeing.  You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/426126